# Subtracting percent of each cell from itself then subtracting a constant from each of those numbers and adding all of them together

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have an excel spreadsheet with several PayPal payements in a column.  I want account for the paypal fee; which is 2.9%+.30cents per transaction.  How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data is in cell A1, enter the following formula in cell B1:

```
= (A1 * .029) + .3
```

This will put the paypal fee in the cell B1.

If you want to show the total amount of the transaction after paypal takes its fee, use this formula:

```
= A1 - ((A1 * .029) + .3)
```

Answer (score 0):

In a new column you could have a formula like:

```
=A1-(A1*0.029)+0.3
```